# validcharacters problems in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have an aspx page 
I have a textBox which is a custom control .
when I use this textbox 
it's rendered like below

and when I remove validcharacters="0123456789" from this tag everything is nice in firefox but when I have this property in my tag, I could not write anything in this textbox.

IMPORTANT : every thing in chrome is ok.

Comment: Is that attribute even valid? I see no results in Google. Anyway, just use HTML5's `pattern` attribute.

Comment: actually this is a component which i'm using... in fact this is component is compatible with IE and Chrome but unfortunately it does not work in Firefox ... Please give me a hand to figure out this matter.